# Cannot load package: it contains unit which is also contained in another package

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I am developing a Delphi 7 application with MDI child forms in packages. I use  common units (for example Zlib to compressing and decompressing) in some packages. I load the first group of packages and its form1 (which contains zlib,  used in the uses section), and when I load the second group of packages with the same condition (form2 which contains zlib) while the first packages are loaded, I get the error "Cannot load package A it contains unit 'UtilityPasZlib' which is also contained in package B."

I read some articles; they suggest using the UtilityPasZlib in the requires section, but I dont know how to do this.

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devcommon/compdirsweakpackaging_xml.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Units may not appear in two or more different packages that are loaded into the same program. In your situation, you must move the shared units into a separate package that is used by your other existing packages.

It's not obvious to me what `UtilityPasZlib` is, but perhaps you don't need it. After all, Delphi 7 ships with a `ZLib` unit.

Comment: Hi thanks , I made a package and import 2 units , After compile it returns "[Error] Package1.dpk(32): Package 'rtl' already contains unit 'ZLib' " . What is the problem ?

Comment: Exact same problem. The error message tells you what the issue is. The `rtl` package contains `ZLib`, and so does one of your packages.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I have the same problem and I cannot understand how to do that. If I remove the shared unit from my components and move it elsewhere, then how can i compile them ?